# Django Template won't escape HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I have a model that extends a `django-mailbox` email message. If an email message is in text format, `as_html()` will convert the text to html. (It wraps the text in a `<pre>` tag.)

```
class EmailReply(models.Model):

    def as_html(self):
        if self.message.html:
            return self.message.html
        elif self.message.text:
            context = {
                'email': self.message.text
            }
            return mark_for_escaping(
                render_to_string(
                    APP_NAME+'/email/text_as_html.html',
                    context
                )
            )

    message = models.OneToOneField('django_mailbox.Message')

    ...
```

I want to display several email messages in a single html page. I have a view that iterates over several EmailReply objects. Rather than linking to the message, I need to include the html in the iframe's srcdoc. (I'm converting the page to PDF, and the converter works better having everything in one page.)

```
{% for email in emails %}
<div class="page">
    <ul>
        <li>Subject: {{ email.message.subject }}</li>
    </ul>
    <iframe srcdoc="{{ email.as_html|escape }}" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox></iframe>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

For messages that have an html component, the html is escaped:

```
<div class="page">
    <ul>
        <li>Subject: Example 1</li>
    </ul>
    <iframe srcdoc="&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;[...]" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox></iframe>
</div>
```

However, messages that are text come through without being escaped:

```
<div class="page">
    <ul>
        <li>Subject: Example 2</li>
    </ul>
    <iframe srcdoc="
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Email Reply</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
[...]
</body>
</html>
" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox></iframe>
</div>
```

I use both `mark_for_escaping()` and the `escape` template filter, but when the output is a text email, it is still not escaped. Why not?

(Using Django 1.10.)

Comment: Have you tried [force_escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-force_escape)? It seems that's what should be used to escape a string.

Comment: What does "text_as_html.html" look like?

Comment: Do not use `mark_for_escaping()`. It is deprecated.

Comment: `force_escape` worked. (And I removed `mark_for_escaping()`.) ... Although, I still think that Django should escape this without having to be told to, no?